# Drupal 8 override Theme Hook Page file suggestion

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I know there are some tutorials online about how to do this, but for some reason I doesn't work.

I would like to add a file theme suggestion on the "Theme Hook: Page" level of the template with the name of the content type (this way I can let all items of this content type use this template).

So, I add this to my `MYTHEME.theme.php` file:

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
   if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
       array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'page__node__' . $node->getType());
    }
}
```

So you would expect the following output:

- page--node--19.html.twig
- page--node--%.html.twig
- **page--node--dish.html.twig // Gets not added**
- page--node.html.twig
- page.html.twig

I already tried clearing the cache. I'm using Drupal 8.1

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was not with the function but with the filename. My file name was `MYTHEME.theme.php` but it should have been `MYTHEME.theme`.

That's why the code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

simply add this file in to you theme floder `node--typeName.html.twig`
no need any function. now your content type should use this template

Comment: This only alters the template on the "node"-level. And not on the "page"-level. My guess is I do need the template hook method?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by the following code, which seems somewhat same as your code

```
if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__node__'.$node->bundle();
}
```